# COUNT inside CONNECT BY

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm having a `connect by` statement which returns me every project and its childrens.

Now I want to have the amount of returned rows in the SELECT statement so far. What I tried:

```
SELECT 
      PROJECT_NAME,
      PROJECT_LEVEL,
      count(PROJECT_ID) 
from PROJECTS
where PROJECT_NAME is not null 
      connect by prior PROJECTS.id = PROJECTS.parent_id
      start with PROJECTS.id = 8572435
```

I'm getting "not a single-group group function".

Adding GROUP BY:

```
SELECT 
      PROJECT_NAME,
      PROJECT_LEVEL,
      count(PROJECT_ID) 
from PROJECTS
where PROJECT_NAME is not null 
      connect by prior PROJECTS.id = PROJECTS.parent_id
      start with PROJECTS.id = 8572435
GROUP BY PROJECT_NAME, PROJECT_LEVEL
```

RETURNS me 1 in every row.

Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is mentioned in the error itself. Please try using group by clause at the end of sql statement which will solve your problem definately :) You cannot use aggregrate function for 1 column if you selecting multiple columns. You have to use Group By clause for other columns those are not use with aggregrate function :)

```
SELECT 
      PROJECT_NAME,
      PROJECT_LEVEL,
      count(PROJECT_ID) 
from PROJECTS
where PROJECT_NAME is not null 
      connect by prior PROJECTS.id = PROJECTS.parent_id
      start with PROJECTS.id = 8572435
      Group By PROJECT_NAME, PROJECT_LEVEL
```

Comment: As you have mentioned you want to have amount of rows returned so why dont you use sum function instead of count ?

Comment: COUNT(*) OVER () will give me 89 in every result row.